# Dynamic CRM Shared Variables Thread Safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a Dynamic CRM plugin which has two steps. One is running on pre-create and second is running on post-create. I have used Shared Variables. I am setting the values in shared variables on pre-create and retriving the values on post-create.

Now is it thread safe. If two users trigger the same plugin in same org would not they over write each others data?

Set values in Shared Variables:

```
context.SharedVariables.Add("statecode", stateCodeValue);
context.SharedVariables.Add("statuscode", statusCodeValue);
```

Get values from Shared Variables:

```
int statecode = (int)context.SharedVariables["statecode"];
int statuscode = (int)context.SharedVariables["statuscode"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is thread-safe. The `IPluginExecutionContext` passed to your plugin class is an object that is uniquely created for a plugin execution pipeline. Shared variables are passed from one stage to the next (PreValidation => PreOperation => PostOperation => AsyncOperation).

An execution pipeline is specific for any single operation processed by the CRM platform. (E.g. a create or update message regarding a specific record.)